DISTINCT query in Sequelize using belongsToMany relation and including many tables
I have two related models Product and Category which are joined with belongsToMany relation. I'm trying to fetch those products which has some categories using [Op.in] operator but can't get distinct values.
async findAll(page, perPage, by, direction, searchWord, categories) {
     let options = {
        where: { published: true },
        limit: perPage,
        order: [[by, direction]],
        offset: (page - 1) * perPage,
        raw: true,
        distinct: true,
     };
    // Category include
      if (categories) {
        if (typeof categories === "string") categories = Array(categories);
        categories = categories.map((cat) => parseInt(cat));
        
        options.include = {
          model: CategoryModel,
          where: { id: { [Op.in]: categories } },
          through: { attributes: [] },
        };
      }
      result = await ProductModel.findAndCountAll(options);
      console.log(result);
    } else {
      result = await ProductModel.findAll({ where: { published: true } });
    }
    return result;

The count value returned by findAndCountAll function is good but the returned rows have recurring rows.
sql result below
{
  count: 3,
  rows: [
    {
      id: 8,
      name: 'Tulejka',
      'Categories.id': 10,
      'Categories.name': 'Koła'
    },
    {
      id: 10,
      name: 'Flansza EGR',
      'Categories.id': 9,
      'Categories.name': 'Wyciągarki'
    },
    {
      id: 13,
      name: 'Szybka',
      'Categories.id': 9,
      'Categories.name': 'Wyciągarki'
    },
    {
      id: 13,
      name: 'Szybka',
      'Categories.id': 10,
      'Categories.name': 'Koła'
    }
  ]
}

I have tried separate, distinct, Sequelize.literal[] etc.
I would like to do this in one sequelize findAndCountAll with proper options.
Alternative:
Filtering results
result.rows = result.rows.filter(
    (row, index, self) => index === self.findIndex((r) => r.id === row.id)
  );


did you try raw: false?

It actually seems to work
